# normalizr setting a new property and grouping

Tags: json, react-redux, normalizr

I have a JSON returning from my API.

```
[{
        "_id": "id1",
        "userId": "u1",
        "createdOn": "2017-11-13T19:24:05.269Z"
    }, {
        "_id": "id2",
        "userId": "u2",
        "createdOn": "2017-11-13T19:23:59.777Z"
    }, {
        "_id": "id3",
        "userId": "u3",
        "createdOn": "2017-11-09T17:34:14.507Z"
    }, {
        "_id": "id4",
        "userId": "u4",
        "createdOn": "2017-11-08T18:15:54.303Z"
    }
]
```

First I need to split createdOn ( like createdOn.split("T")[0]) and set a new property createdDate which contains a date only string. Then I want to categorize this based on the new property createdDate and then group them into items which are created on the same date. So I am trying to get a structure as follows.

```
{
    "history": {
        "2017-11-08": {
            "id4": {
                "_id": "id4",
                "userId": "u4",
                "createdOn": "2017-11-08T18:15:54.303Z",
                "createdDate": "2017-11-08"
            }
        },
        "2017-11-09": {
            "id3": {
                "_id": "id3",
                "userId": "u3",
                "createdOn": "2017-11-09T17:34:14.507Z",
                "createdDate": "2017-11-09"
            }
        },
        "2017-11-13": {
            "id1": {
                "_id": "id1",
                "userId": "u1",
                "createdOn": "2017-11-13T19:24:05.269Z",
                "createdDate": "2017-11-13"
            },
            "id2": {
                "_id": "id2",
                "userId": "u2",
                "createdOn": "2017-11-13T19:23:59.777Z",
                "createdDate": "2017-11-13"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I tried different options with 'processStrategy'(for spliting date time string) and also multiple schema

```
     export const historySchema = new schema.Entity(
      "history",
      {},
      { idAttribute: "_id" },
    );

    export const historyGroupingSchema = new schema.Entity(
      "history",
      { el: [historySchema] },
      { idAttribute: "createdDate" },
    );

normalize(history, [
      historyGroupingSchema,
    ])
```

but doesn't work. How to do this with [normalizr](https://github.com/paularmstrong/normalizr).

Answer (score -1):

To Categorize objects based on just date part of created date you need to loop through each object and parse the created date (which is 2nd question) i have created a function which will return just date. you can change the format there are other good js library available specially `momentjs`
Once you parse the dates then you can loop the array and fetch the objects with same date

```js
var p=[{
        "_id": "id1",
        "userId": "u1",
        "createdOn": "2017-11-13T19:24:05.269Z"
    }, {
        "_id": "id2",
        "userId": "u2",
        "createdOn": "2017-11-13T19:23:59.777Z"
    }, {
        "_id": "id3",
        "userId": "u3",
        "createdOn": "2017-11-09T17:34:14.507Z"
    }, {
        "_id": "id4",
        "userId": "u4",
        "createdOn": "2017-11-08T18:15:54.303Z"
    }
];

  function getDatepart(createdOn)
  {
    var dateFieldValue= new Date(createdOn)
    var year = dateFieldValue.getFullYear()+"";
    var month = (dateFieldValue.getMonth()+1)+"";
    var day = dateFieldValue.getDate()+"";
    var dateFormat = year + "-" + month + "-" + day;//use your format
    console.log(dateFormat)
    return dateFormat;
    
  }
  getDatepart(p[0].createdOn)
```

Comment: I am trying to get this done by normalizr[https://github.com/paularmstrong/normalizr], For getting date component what I mentioned is enough for me (split with "T" and take first element)